# What does "Turritopsis dohrnii" mean?

Tags: scientific-names

*Turritopsis dohrnii* is the binomial name of the [immortal jellyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turritopsis_dohrnii).

I know that those names are often only *inspired* by Latin and Greek so I was not wondering about the literal meaning but about the roots that were used to create this word. In particular the *hr* digram feels strange to me and I don't know of any Latin word with it.

Comment: I would assume the species name refers to someone with the surname Dohr, possibly the discoverer.

Comment: @dbmag9 If I understand this database correctly http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=151801 it was discovered by Weismann

Comment: The specific name is very likely to honor [Anton Dohrn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Dohrn). It's common practice to name species and genera after prominent naturalists. Re: the genus, I have no clear idea yet.

Comment: @Rafael You must be right for that part of the name, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This species was originally called *[Dendroclava dohrnii](http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=151801)* in honor of [Anton Dohrn](https://www.szn.it/index.php/it/) (as Rafael noted in his comment). This is affirmed by August Weismann in his book:

> Diesen Namen schlage ich zu Ehren des Gründers der vortefflichen
> zoologischen Station in Neapel für eine bisher unbekannte Clavide vor,
> welche im Golf von Neapel in grösserer Tief lebi. (*[Die Entstehung
> Der Sexualzellen Bei Den Hydromedusen](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/9646925#page/47/mode/1up)*, pg. 26)
>
> I propose this name in honor of the founder of the excellent
> zoological station in Naples for a hitherto unknown clavid, which
> lives in greater depth in the Gulf of Naples.

The parent of *Turritopsis dohrnii* is *[Turritopsis mccrady](https://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=117056)*, and the reason given for assigning this name is as follows:

> The present sub-genus, for which I propose the name Turritopsis, is
> distinguished from Turris by the following peculiarities: The swimbell
> is remarkably thin, having no accumulation of transparent tissue above
> as in Oceania and Turris, but the whole appears to be a muscular mass
> covered by epithelium within and without. ([pg. 56](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/42536539#page/84/mode/1up))

As far as the name *Turris*, that is attributed to [René-Primevère Lesson](https://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=718815). Although Lesson doesn't give his reason for naming it as such, I agree with Job Rozemond that it probably means *[tower](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dturris)*. The description given by Lesson kind of sounds like a tower:

> Ombrelle allongé, cylindrique et pyramidal, tronqué à la base que a
> huit tentacules, dilatés et échancrés à leur attache; muni de quatre
> lignes vasculaires, longitudinales. (*[Zoophytes](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/3803187#page/11/mode/1up)*, pg. 283)
>
> Long umbrella, cylindrical and pyramidal, truncated at the base with
> eight tentacles, dilated and indented at their attachment; provided
> with four longitudinal vascular lines.

Comment: The sources you have collected answer the question perfectly, thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 5):

**Turritopsis** is a compound word. Its parts are [turris](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dturris), tower, and ὄψις (opsis), appearance.

So the jellyfish is "something that looks like a tower" and indeed, if you look up images of it, there is something to say for this association.

As Rafael observed, Dohrnii must refer to Anton Dohrn.

Comment: Thank you! I've thought about this association but I assumed they wouldn't mix Latin and Greek like that

Comment: @Laravel, they do mix both languages a lot, more so since the XX century, as Latin and Greek become less known